# How to get Travis CI to build and test xcode projects hosted on Github?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, github, travis-ci, xcode-project

I have some open source code hosted on github for adding a [block based category to UITextField](https://github.com/haaakon/UITextField-Blocks). I have added a .travis.yml file to get travis CI to build and run the code on every push. [Link to The Travis CI warning](https://travis-ci.org/haaakon/UITextField-Blocks) . It successfully builds the project.
The warning i get when running the .travis.yml script is:

```
WARNING: Using Objective-C testing without specifying a scheme and either
a workspace or a project is deprecated.
```

The example project that i want to run is located in the folder /UITextView Blocks Example/
How can i add to the .travis.yml file to run this project? 
My travis.yml file now consists of

```
language: objective-c
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update 2017

[skypecakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37168/skypecakes) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607894/how-to-get-travis-ci-to-build-and-test-xcode-projects-hosted-on-github/19651894#comment78615443_19651894):

> For anyone using **XCode 8 and higher**: `xctool` is no longer supported, and does not work.
>   Use **[xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)** instead.

---

Original answer (2013)

You can check [this tutorial](https://github.com/facebook/xctool#continuous-integration), which explains:

> `xctool` is an excellent choice for running your tests under a continuous integration server such as Travis CI or Jenkins.
>   **In order to your run your tests within a continuous integration environment, you must create Shared Schemes for your application target and ensure that all dependencies (such as CocoaPods) are added explicitly to the Scheme**.
>   To do so:
>
> 1. Open up the Manage Schemes sheet by selecting the Product menu > Schemes > Manage Schemes...
> 2. Locate your application target in the list. Ensure that the Shared checkbox in far right hand column of the sheet is checked.
> 3. If your application or test targets include cross-project dependencies such as CocoaPods, then you will need to ensure that they have been configured as explicit dependencies. To do so:
>
>    - Highlight your application target and hit the Edit... button to open the Scheme editing sheet.
>    - Click the Build tab in the left-hand panel of the Scheme editor.
>    - Click the + button and add each dependency to the project. CocoaPods will appears as static library named Pods.
>    - Drag the dependency above your application target so that it is built first.
>
> **You will now have a new file in the `xcshareddata/xcschemes` directory underneath your Xcode project**.
>   This is the shared Scheme that you just configured.
>   Check this file into your repository and xctool will be able to find and execute your tests on the next CI build.
>
> For more flexibility, you can also control how Travis installs and invokes xctool:

```
language: objective-c
before_install:
    - brew update
    - brew install xctool
script: xctool -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp test
```

---

That last configuration is similar to the approach illustrated in [this other tutorial](http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2013/05/07/using-travis-ci-and-xctool-to-build-and-test-ios/):

> Once you have linked your repo the next step would be to add a `.travis.yml` file to the root of the repo.

```
  language: objective-c

  before_script: travis/before_script.sh
  script: travis/script.sh
```

> - First I’m telling Travis that this is an objective-c project.
> - Next I tell Travis how I’d like it to do CI against this repo by giving it instructions on what scripts it should run in order to actually perform a build.
>
> I also give some extra instructions on what to do just prior to running a build.
>   **It’s quite common to put all the build steps inline right in the .travis.yml file, but I prefer to actually create bash scripts in my repo inside a travis directory in my git repo and then just refer to those scripts from my `.travis.yml`.**
>   **This keeps the `.yml` file nice and small, and also makes it easy for me to test the travis build scripts locally**.
>
> We gave Travis a `before_script` in the `.yml` file above. This is intended to be used by the Travis agent to download tools needed as part of the build. Here’s what it looks like:

```
travis/before_script.sh

#!/bin/sh
set -e

brew update
brew install xctool
```

> Very simple. We just use homebrew to install `xctool` on the build agent.
>   All travis build agents come with `homebrew` pre-installed, but sometimes the formula aren’t up to date, so it’s best to run a `brew update` before attempting a `brew install`.
>   That’s all we need to do to prepare our agent for the build.
>
> Next let’s look at the build script itself:

```
travis/script.sh

#!/bin/sh
set -e

xctool -workspace MyWorkspace -scheme MyScheme build test
```

> Again, this is really simple.
>   We first do a basic sanity check by **asking `xctool` to build our app, specifying a workspace and scheme**.
>   This just checks that we don’t have any compilation errors.
>   Assuming that succeeds `xctool` will then build and run the unit testing target for our app, launching the Simulator on the Travis agent if needed.

Comment: For anyone using XCode 8 and higher: xctool no longer supported, does not work. Use xcodebuild instead.

Comment: @skypecakes Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify the language is Objective-C in the `.travis.yml` file, the CI server will by default use their [adapted version of `osx-cibuild.sh`](https://gist.github.com/henrikhodne/73151fccea7af3201f63).  This will look for any workspaces in the current directory, and build all default targets.

Since your repo doesn't have any workspaces in the root (they are under `Examples`), it can't find what to build, and so won't build anything.

You can either move your project file from under `Examples` to the root, or specify what to build by setting `XCWORKSPACE` in your Travis CI config, or you could specify a custom script to run and then invoke `xcodebuild` yourself. Setting the workspace config is probably the preferred option; don't customise it if you don't need to.

Add something like the following to your `.travis.yml`:

```
env:
  - XCWORKSPACE="Examples/UITextField-Blocks Example.xcodeproj"
```

(The quotes are there due to the filename having an internal space.)

It's worth examining the `osx-cibuild.sh` script to see just how it works, and how you can customise its behaviour by setting various environment variables.

Useful references:

- [Travis CI: Building and Objective-C Test](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/objective-c/)
- [Travis CI: Build Configuration](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/)
- [Travis CI: OS X CI Environment](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/osx-ci-environment/)